# Best practice for passing messages from GLSurfaceView to MainActivity in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm doing some OpenGL ES 2.0 coding with Android on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

I've implemented the MyRenderer class according to the Android OpenGL tutorials, but I'd like to be able to get some debug information back to the MainActivity, such as an error message if a shader compiler failed. Unfortunately all approaches I've tried for getting the error message back to the main activity thus far have failed.

At first I was going to just have the rendering class itself pop up an alert dialog box using the AlertDialogBuilder class, but since GLSurfaceView.renderer isn't of the right type, that obviously didn't work. And since GLSurfaceView.renderer isn't an activity, I also couldn't have it spawn an activity to display the information.

My approach then was to have my MainActivity implement an interface called AlertReporter that only has one method:

```
public interface AlertCallback {
    void alertAndDie(String alertString);    
}
```

I've implemented the method in my MainActivity, but whenever I have the method do anything (spawn an alert box, create a new text box activity, etc...) the program crashes. I'm assuming (and could be wrong) that this is because I'm calling a method in the MainActivity from the rendering thread (what GLSurfaceView spawns when it creates my renderer).

So long story short, my question is this: 
What is the best practice for getting this error information back to the MainActivity thread so that I can display it?

As a side question, is the onCreateSurface method in the renderer even the best place to handle all of my openGL initialization such as shader compilation?

Comment: You should use the Log in logcat

Comment: You can also use a handler to interrupt the glthread

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the log class for debugging information

```
Log.d("FPSCounter", "fps: " + frames);
```

For android ui components you would have to make a handler to interrupt the glthread correctly witch is why you are crashing, I say use logs though, as that would be best practice

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using the logger but I've run into the glGetShaderInfoLog returns empty string bug that is apparently still alive even in Android 4.2... :(

Comment: I never used shaderlog before, I was unaware of that

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I used for doing something similar. I use a global variable to hold the handle of a TextView created in the Activity class. The global is assigned by making a call from the Activity class to the render class.

Code in render class:

```
private static TextView glbTv1 = null;

public void assignTextviewGlobalHandles(TextView tv1){
    glbTv1 = tv1;

}

public void mycallbacktomainactivitymehod(){

     if(glbTv1 !=null){
       final myMainActivity activity=(myMainActivity) this.context;
       activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run()
               {
                 //glbTv1 is assigned through a TextView varaible created in the Activity class, by making a call into the render class.
                 glbTv1.setText(String.valueOf(f_jetPos));
               }
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: how can you call the render from the activity class ?